# Dynamically decide columns in SSIS connectors for salesforce

Tags: ssis, salesforce, kingswaysoft, cdata-drivers, ssis-powerpack

I want migrate data from salesforce to SQL server and I am using SSIS connectors for salesforce. I am creating single SSIS package which fetch data for all objects and insert into SQL server. I tried using following connectors for salesforce.

Connector 1 : Kingswaysoft
                https://www.kingswaysoft.com/

Connector 2 : CData
                https://www.cdata.com/kb/articles/ado-ssistask-sf.rst

Connector 3 : SSIS PowerPack - 
                https://zappysys.com/onlinehelp/ssis-powerpack/index.htm
                https://zappysys.com/products/ssis-powerpack/ssis-salesforce-source-connector/

In all the connectors I am unable to provide different columns(salesforce fields) dynamically in SOQL query using SSIS variables.

Comment: SSIS is build for static metadata ETLs. If you want one solution for all objects (with dynamic objects and SQL tables) you might need to implement a custom process in C# or VB that uses Salesforce's BulkApi.

Comment: Could you please provide me with reference links. I am a C# beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that SSIS is for static ETL & you can work around with C# script task for dynamic metadata.

As an Alternative, you can try conditional branches and run two different tasks based on expression. Read [Add expressions to precedence constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/precedence-constraints?view=sql-server-2017#add-expressions-to-precedence-constraints).

Not sure how many dynamic columns we are talking here, but for discussion sake let’s take 2 different columns has to be filled in salesforce destination based on source column, then have 2 branch.